# neo4j - query DB while updating graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, crud

I have a script that runs in the background and "fix" nodes, which means it does a lot of removing and creating relationships.
While this script is running, I try to run the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (pr:Property)-[r2:SIMILAR*0..1]-()<-[r]-(it:Item)
WHERE pr.name in ["BLACK","BLACK2"] and toFloat(it.crawler) >= 3.8
return pr.name, type(r),it
```

I run it a few times. Sometimes I get an answer and sometimes I get something like:

```
Unable to load RELATIONSHIP with id 9765815.
Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound
```

Of course the 'id' changes all the time.

I understand that in the middle of computation, some of the relationships change. But I thought neo4j knows how to handle it and return the last "true" results (CRUD). 
Is there a way to ignore the changes and return the current results?

I'm running neo4j-enterprise 2.0.3.

EDIT :

I'm running the query both from the browser and from the nodejs neo4j agent

Comment: are you running the query using webadmin?

Comment: just edited the post...

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j is fully ACID, the "I" meaning isolation, i.e. transactions should not see each other's uncommitted modifications. Therefore, you're right in saying that Neo4j should handle it.

Here's what I think is happening. The Cypher query, since it executes in a single transaction, always succeeds, no problem there. But something happens afterwards: the "browser" that ships with Neo4j always displays all relationships between nodes that it is displaying, no matter if you asked for them or not. I'm assuming that loading these is part of a different transaction than your original Cypher query. In that case, it can encounter relationships that it thinks exist, but have been deleted in the meantime by your script.

This is an assumption, but should be easy to verify. If it's correct, then:

1. if you change `it` (the whole node) to `it.someProperty`, then the issue should never occur
2. if you run the original cypher query from (let's say) the command line or via REST, but not from the browser, the issue should never occur

Please let us know your findings. Cheers

Comment: Thanks... The query fails also when I run the REST client from the nodejs plugin. So, I'm guessing that's not the issue. If the Cypher query is isolated, then it's really weird. I will try to see again what is the error message when running from the nodejs

Comment: How did it go? Could you post the code that's failing? Thx